# tcsh script function should have a magenta color shows blue

Tags: linux, tcsh

tcsh script showing below, for the option "--cwp" in the function "mri-glmfit-sim", it should have a magenta color instead of blue, so how do I modify the script accordingly？

```
#!/bin/tcsh

setenv study $argv[1]

foreach meas (thickness area)
  foreach hemi (lh rh)
    foreach dir ({$hemi}.{$meas}-rate.{$study}.glmdir)
     mri_glmfit-sim \
      --glmdir {$dir} \
      --perm 1000 1.3 abs \ 
      --cwp 0.05 \      # should in magenta color as other --options but shows blue
      --2spaces
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What actual colors the ANSI palette maps to is up to your terminal's configuration. Bash doesn't directly control them.

Comment: Also, tcsh is not bash -- it's not even anything _like_ bash; it's from a completely incompatible family of shells (that has, [for very good reasons](https://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt), been mostly assigned to the dustbin of history).

Comment: (also, nothing in this script is doing anything that looks like making any attempt to send terminal control sequences that would change the syntax highlighting; if that highlighting is being done by something like an editor or IDE, you should be asking a question about that editor).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Charles, I don't know much about the differences between tsch and bash. But I follow your advice and format it into a bash script:  find ./ -type d -name '*.glmdir' -exec bash -c 'for i in "$@"; do mri_glmfit-sim --glmdir "$i" --perm 1000 1.3 abs --cwp  0.05 --2spaces; done' _ {} +;  It worked perfectly.